# <select> with selection to equal the index of the source array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I want to select the index of the selected item in the array data source. Or, put it in other words, I want the `value` attribute of an `<option>` to equal the index value, e.g. `0, 1, 2, ...`:

```
<select name="networkname" class="form-control" id="networkname" ng-model="selectedNetwork" ng-options="network.id as network.name for network in networksList" ng-change="get($index)"</select>
```

Then my output HTML is:

```
<option value="object:57" label="A5 (2 cores, 14336 MB)" selected="selected">A5 (2 cores, 14336 MB)</option>
<option value="object:58" label="A6 (4 cores, 28672 MB)">A6 (4 cores, 28672 MB)</option>
```

But I want the `value` to be:

```
<option value="0" label="A5 (2 cores, 14336 MB)" selected="selected">A5 (2 cores, 14336 MB)</option>
<option value="1" label="A6 (4 cores, 28672 MB)">A6 (4 cores, 28672 MB)</option>
```

This is the source array:

```
$scope.networkList = [
 {id: "A5", name: "A5 (2 cores, 14336 MB)", cpus: 2, disk: null, memory: "14.0 GB"},
 {id: "A6", name: "A6 (4 cores, 28672 MB)", cpus: 4, disk: null, memory: "28.0 GB"}
];
```

Comment: Are you saying you want some empty select options to appear before A5 and A6?

Comment: Please edit this and make it as a **Question**

Comment: no mindparse i want values like 0,1,2,...

Comment: @RavindharKonka, why? If you are properly designing your app, you shouldn't care about what `value` attribute equals to - Angular is doing all the mapping for you, and you will get `network.id` of the selected item.

Comment: @NewDev  for furhter operation i need index of that selected item

Comment: @RavindharKonka, did the answer address your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this with Angular (1.2.x and 1.3.x) that I know of - neither one is perfect:

1. treat the source array as an object source
2. generate options with `ng-repeat`

So, assuming the following VM:

```
$scope.items = [{id: "a", n: "b"}, ...]
```

**Alternative #1**

```
<select ng-model="selectedIndexStr" 
        ng-options="idx as item.n for (idx, item) in items">
```

Drawbacks:

1. `selectedIndexStr` will be a string, not an integer, because `idx` is treated as a property key of an object, not an index of an array. This may or may not work for you, but, to illustrate, if you wanted to set the `ng-model` to a default value, it would have to be `$scope.selectedIndexStr = "0"` (notice the `""`)
2. The order will be based on string comparison of index values. So, if you had more than 10 items, the order would be: `"0", "1", "10", "11", "2", "3", ...`

**Alternative #2**

```
<select ng-model="selectedIndex">
  <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{$index}}" 
          ng-selected="selectedIndex === $index">{{item.n}}</option>
</select>
```

Drawback here is that it is more verbose as it doesn't use `ng-options`

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2uE7tn7ame4NXR4X3dd?p=preview) showing the alternatives

**Off-topic:**

In a typical case, though, one would want the actual selected object, or sometimes - a property of that object. If you rely on an index of the array where the object is stored, then perhaps you should re-evaluate your ViewModel design.

So, the following would make the most sense to me:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.n for item in items">
```

or,

```
<select ng-model="selectedItemId" ng-options="item.id as item.n for item in items">
```